# Parse XML in its original orde

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I am parsing xml using jquery. I attached an image that shows the sort of xml I want to parse. As you can see that it has several tags but I need to parse following in the order as it is appeared in the image.

```
ROUTE
   LENGTH time dist
   WALK  time dist
   LINE  code
      STOP                   //<--- this stop means all stops in this line tag
         NAME val            //<--- val of every stop inside line tag
      STOP                   //<--- this stop means all stops in this line tag
         NAME val            //<--- val of every stop inside line tag
      STOP                   //<--- this stop means all stops in this line tag
         NAME val            //<--- val of every stop inside line tag
   LINE code
      STOP                   //<--- this stop means all stops in this line tag
         NAME val            //<--- val of every stop inside line tag
      STOP                   //<--- this stop means all stops in this line tag
         NAME val            //<--- val of every stop inside line tag
      STOP                   //<--- this stop means all stops in this line tag
         NAME val            //<--- val of every stop inside line tag
   WALK time dist
```

Note: there could be 1, 2 or more than 2 LINES tags.

My current code does show data but for only one i.e. first LINE and only first STOP inside that LINE. So how can I parse this xml so that I could display it as it is in XML?

Here is my code

```
 parseXMLForRoute = function (xmlObject) {
    var xmlObj = $(xmlObject).find('ROUTE');

    xmlObj.each(function () {
        var el          = $(this),
            startTime   = el.find('WALK').find('LENGTH').attr('time'),
            distance    = el.find('WALK').find('LENGTH').attr('dist'),
            routeTime   = el.find('LENGTH').attr('time'),
            routeDist   = el.find('LENGTH').attr('dist'),
            busNumber   = el.find('LINE').attr('code').slice(1, 4),
            busStops    = el.find('LINE').find('STOP').find('NAME').attr('val');

        container.append(createDOMElement('h4', '', '', 'Departure'))
                 .append(createDOMElement('p', '', '', from))
                 .append(createDOMElement('p', '', '', "Route Time: " + routeTime))
                 .append(createDOMElement('p', '', '', "Route Dist: " + routeDist))
                 .append(createDOMElement('section', '', '', 'WALK PIC'))
                 .append(createDOMElement('p', '', '', "Walk Time: " + startTime))
                 .append(createDOMElement('p', '', '', "Walk Dist: " + distance))
                 .append(createDOMElement('p', '', '', 'BUS PIC'))
                 .append(createDOMElement('p', '', '', "Bus Number: " + parseLineNumbers(xmlObj)))
                 .append(createDOMElement('p', '', '', "Bus Stops: " + busStops));

        //console.log($(this).find('WALK'));
    });
    console.log($(xmlObject));
},

parseLineNumbers = function (xmlObject) {
    console.log('len: ' + $(xmlObject).find('LINE').length);
    $(xmlObject).find('LINE').each(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr('code').slice(1, 4));
    });
    //console.log($(xmlObject).find('LINE').attr('code').slice(1, 4));
},

createDOMElement = function (tagName, classs, id, data) {
    return '<' + tagName + ' class="' + classs + '" id="' + id + '">' + data + '</' + tagName + '>';
}
```

here is xml

[image]

**UPDATE**

I want to have output something similar to below

```
Starting street address
WALK this amount of distance(e.g. 1 meter) for some time(e.g. 1 min)
STOP name // after walking then user reached to this stop
code // code attribute inside LINE tag which is a bus number
then display the name and times of all stops in this LINE
code // code attribute inside SECOND LINE
then display all the stops name and times in this second LINE
then walk for some distance(e.g. 1 meter) and some time(e.g. 1 min)
Destination address
```

Comment: I don't understand... You want to parse XML so that you display as XML? What does that mean? Why would you need to parse it if you already have it in the format you want it in?

Comment: No. I want to parse XML in the order as it is but I will display the attribute values. Please ask if it is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the bus lines and inside each bus line over the bus stops. I hope this leads you in the right directiion.

```
parseXMLForRoute = function (xmlObject) {    
    var route = $(xmlObject).find('ROUTE');
    route.each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var startTime = el.find('WALK').find('LENGTH').attr('time');
        var distance = el.find('WALK').find('LENGTH').attr('dist');
        var routeTime = el.find('LENGTH').attr('time');
        var routeDist = el.find('LENGTH').attr('dist');
        var lines = el.find('LINE');

        container.append(createDOMElement('h4', '', '', 'Departure'))
            .append(createDOMElement('p', '', '', from))
            .append(createDOMElement('p', '', '', "Route Time: " + routeTime))
            .append(createDOMElement('p', '', '', "Route Dist: " + routeDist))
            .append(createDOMElement('section', '', '', 'WALK PIC'))
            .append(createDOMElement('p', '', '', "Walk Time: " + startTime))
            .append(createDOMElement('p', '', '', "Walk Dist: " + distance))

        // now iterate over every bus line
        lines.each(function() {
           var el = $(this);
           var busCode = el.attr('code').slice(1,4);
           container.append(createDOMElement('p', '', '', 'BUS PIC'))
               .append(createDOMElement('p', '', '', 'Bus Number: ' + busCode));
           var stops = el.find('STOP');
           var stops_list = []; // this will hold bus stop names

           // now iterate over every bus stop 
            stops.each(function() {
               var el = $(this).find('NAME'); 
               stops_list.push(el.attr('val'));
            });
            container.append(createDOMElement('p', '', '', 'Bus Stops: ' + stops_list.join(',')));
        });
    });​
}
```

**Note:** if `.find()` matches multiple elements it returns a set of matched elements. For example `el.find('WALK')` in the example above actually contains two elements:

```
el.find('WALK')[0].find('LENGTH').attr('time') == 3.540
el.find('WALK')[1].find('LENGTH').attr('time') == 1.743
```

If you don't specify an index, you will be dealing with the first element

```
el.find('WALK').find('LENGTH').attr('time') == 3.540
```